# htaccess exclude URL from Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I've got some simple redirect for maintarance mode like:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|svg)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It's working fine.. But when i want to exclude one more URL like:

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin($|/)
```

It's don't redirect properly...

Answer (score 0):

I've add RewriteCond for IP, just for my network.. Work's fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.123.123.123
```